# What is the difference between "in the sciences", "in sciences" and "in science"?

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural

Is there any difference between "in the sciences", "in sciences" and "in science"?

Examples in today's news:

https://www.bostonglobe.com/business/2016/09/21/umass-lowell-gets-grant-work-promoting-women-faculty-sciences/es4WeQjq6VcxUNMCtt9pcJ/story.htm:

> UMass Lowell receives $3.5m grant to work on promoting women faculty **in the sciences**.

http://www.nature.com/news/socio-economic-inequality-in-science-is-on-the-rise-1.20654 :

> Socio-economic inequality **in science** is on the rise.

I also ran across "in sciences", example https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01420:

> A Comparative Study of Interdisciplinarity **in Sciences** in Brazil, South Korea, Turkey, and USA.

Comment: I would say "science" refers to the field of science in general, while "sciences" refers to the individual fields of science (some subset of all fields of science).

Comment: Your UMass Lowell link is either broken or maybe needs a subscription?

Comment: @Peter just a crappy newspaper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your examples they basically mean the same thing.

> in the sciences

is usually understood to mean **all the branches** of scientific study. One could be more specific

> life sciences
>   hard sciences
>   biological sciences
>   social sciences

Your second example

> in science

can have the same meaning as "in the sciences" when speaking about the collection of scientific fields, but it can also mean using scientific deduction and process to figure out an answer.

> We place our faith in science.

Your final example

> in sciences

is part of a title for a research paper.  In the paper the author cites several different scientific fields, not all, so, using "the sciences" would not be appropriate since it is not all inclusive.  The author might have used "non-social sciences" since (s)he is referencing physics, chemistry, and molecular biology.  It may also be partly due to *headlinese*.